# differential equation power series solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this equation using power series 
$$
  (1-x)y"-xy'+y=0  
$$
Knowing that $y(0)=-2$ and $y'(0)=6$.
Please I need someone's help, I get a relation between 
$c(n)$,$c(n+1)$, and $c(n+2)$.

Comment: What is the relation that you get? How far did you get when inserting $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$ into the differential equation? (Please add additional contents to the question. One should be able to ignore the comments.)

Comment: I doubt that you'll get a "closed-form" solution to the recurrence equation.  I suspect you're only being asked for the first few terms of the series.

Comment: Thanks a lot...i have solved it and i have found an exact solution where a(n)=a0/n! For all n>=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking

$$\begin{align}
y&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n\\
y'&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_n x^{n-1}\\
y''&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}
\end{align}$$

we have

$$\begin{align}
(1-x)y''-xy'+y&=0\\
(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-x\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_n x^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n&=0\\
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-x\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_n x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n&=0\\
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_n x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n&=0\\
\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_n x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n&=0\\
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(n+1)na_{n+1}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_n x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n&=0\\
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left[(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}-(n+1)na_{n+1}x^{n}-na_n x^{n}+a_n x^n\right]&=0\\
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left[(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-(n+1)na_{n+1}-na_n+a_n \right]x^n&=0
\end{align}$$

then you get

$$\begin{align}
(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-(n+1)na_{n+1}-na_n+a_n&=0\\
(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-(n+1)na_{n+1}+(1-n)a_n&=0\\
a_{n+2}=\frac{(n+1)na_{n+1}+(n-1)a_n}{(n+2)(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

since you got $y(0)=-2$ and $y'(0)=6$ you got $a_0$ and $a_1$ because

$$\begin{align}
y(0)&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n\\
&=a_0\\
y'(0)&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}na_n x^{n-1}\\
&=a_1
\end{align}$$

then with the value of $a_0$ and $a_1$ you can get $a_2,a_3,\cdots$ and then get the solution (valid within the series convergence radius)